"How to Ensure Proper Asset Loading in Laravel Project Using PHP Desktop?"
I am using PHP Desktop to convert my Laravel project into a desktop application. The application runs, but styling and JavaScript files are not loading correctly. When running the Laravel project using php artisan serve, all assets load properly, but without this command, the assets fail to load.
I need a solution that ensures the correct loading of all CSS and JS files within the PHP Desktop environment.
What I have tried:

When I manually start the Laravel server using the command php artisan serve from the www directory, all assets (CSS, JS) load correctly in the PHP Desktop application.

Without running this command, the assets do not load, resulting in pages without proper styling or functionality.



Batch Script:

Created a batch script to automate the process of starting the Laravel server using php artisan serve and launching PHP Desktop. The script also attempts to stop the PHP server when PHP Desktop is closed.

Placed the batch script in various locations, including the root directory and the www directory of the Laravel project.



Settings.json Configuration:

Adjusted the settings.json file of PHP Desktop to point to the correct document root and ensure proper handling of the PHP server and assets.



What I Expected:

Automated Server Start:

I expected the batch script to automatically start the Laravel server using php artisan serve when launching the PHP Desktop application.

The server should serve all assets correctly, ensuring that the desktop application displays with proper styling and functionality.



Proper Asset Loading:

I expected that all CSS and JS files would load correctly, regardless of whether php artisan serve is manually or automatically started.

The desktop application should function identically to the browser version when accessed via php artisan serve.




Despite these attempts, the assets still fail to load properly unless the server is started manually, leading to a need for a reliable solution to automate this process and ensure consistent asset loading in the PHP Desktop environment.

not sure about php desktop, but maybe try to use apache/nginx to serve your PHP/css/js?
